# SQL, How to take into account previously populated records when populating a sequential number ID for a field in a nightly script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to include a clause in a script that runs nightly that will populate a three digit number into a field if that record meets a set of conditions. I will include the script that I have written for this below but I do not know how to account for the numbers that will have been populated on previous nights and keep the new numbers to be populated in sequential order. The numbers must start at 100 and go up by 1 each time a new record is found that meets the conditions.

All help is appreciated.

My current script:

```
DECLARE @myVar NVarchar(50)
SET @myVar = 99


UPDATE  Database1..Thing
SET @myVar = Thing_Number_NEW = @myVar + 1
      WHERE (Thing_Number = '' OR Thing_Number IS NULL)
        AND Thing_Number_Needed = 'Yes'
        AND Symbology IN (2, 3, 55, 66)
        AND Thing_Number_New IS NULL
        AND Last_edited_user is not null
```

Comment: 1st Why `@MyVar` is declared as `NVARCHAR(n)` instead of `INT`? Why you're using an `UPDATE` instead of a `SELECT` to set the value? What 're you trying to do really?

Comment: @MyVar is declared that way because the the field I am trying to fill will only take INT and I am not allowed to change that. I'm using update because I am updating a table

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE Database1..Thing
    SET Thing_Number_NEW = COALESCE(n.max_Thing_Number_NEW + 1, 100)
    FROM (SELECT MAX(Thing_Number_NEW) as max_Thing_Number_NEW FROM Database1..Thing) n
    WHERE (Thing_Number = '' OR Thing_Number IS NULL)
          Thing_Number_Needed = 'Yes' AND
          Symbology IN (2, 3, 55, 66) AND
          Thing_Number_New IS NULL AND
          Last_edited_user is not null;
```

Comment: I think this is close but it's not working. I simulated running it over two nights and it just started over at 100. I'm going to try tweaking it because maybe I altered it incorrectly when I changed the names to the actual names from my database

Comment: @che27 . . . The subquery in the `FROM` clause returns the maximum value in the table.  I don't see how the numbering could restart unless all the values were set to `NULL` in the `Thing_Number_NEW` column.